# Android TextInputLayout Exposed Dropdown Menu

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-textinputlayout

Recently, android introduced a new Exposed dropdown menu for Text Input Layout.

I am trying to add it in my XML but cannot find it.

I am using the latest material design version 1.2.0-alpha05.

Also my style is using the Material components as shown below:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/actionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>
```

However, i still cannot find the new Exposed Drop Down menu as per Material.io.

Can someone please guide me how to get this in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"` in your `TextInputLayout` like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint">

  <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: how we will retrive selected value